# Check permissions, if allowed, publish story to news feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, permissions, publish, feed

What I want to achieve is quite straightforward.

- User clicks button
- App checks for permissions to post to wall and news feed
- If granted, show publish dialogue (with a custom message and image)
- If skipped, close the dialogue and do nothing
- If user had granted permissions to the app before, just show the publish dialogue

I tried doing this with the examples on the developer's page, but the content only appeared on the user's profile page, and not on the news feed.

I'm working with Javascript.

If you could give me a step by step guide on how to do this, I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
That was the code I was testing. It kind of works, but the stories do not appear on the news feed, only on the person's profile page.
Is there anything that must be changed?
Should I try making a new app to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Indeed, I created a new app and now it works... That's strange!